# How to parse an XML with only root element

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

I need to annotate a class for unmarshalling an XML like this:

```
<element>data</element>
```

And I don't know how to do it because the class has to be annotated with `@XmlRootElement` but I need to get the root element value. I know this doesn't work but it's what I have done:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "element")
public Class MyClass{

@XmlElement(name = "element")
protected String elementValue;
public String getElementValue(){...}
public void setElementValue(String el){...}
```

Is there any possibility to get this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for the `@XmlValue` annotation.

**MyClass**

```
package forum13626828;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "element")
public class MyClass{

    protected String elementValue;

    @XmlValue
    public String getElementValue() {
        return elementValue;
    }

    public void setElementValue(String el) {
        this.elementValue = el;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum13626828;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader xml = new StringReader("<element>data</element>");
        MyClass myClass = (MyClass) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(myClass, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<element>data</element>
```

Comment: I changed it to:
`@XmlRootElement(name = "element")
public Class MyClass{

@XmlValue
protected String elementValue;
public String getElementValue(){...}
public void setElementValue(String el){...}`

and still doesn't work

Comment: @hiamex By default you need to add the annotation on the get method.  I have updated the answer to show this.

Comment: I thought it can be in the getter or in the field. Anyway, it still doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan - this should probably be your answer now, not mine. :)  thanks for the updates.

Comment: Ok thank you both, the answer was right, but I was having collateral problems with the JAXBContext.newInstance parameter. Now everythng works perfectly, thanks ;-)